# Does PWM affect current?

Tags: voltage, current, analog, pwm

How does PWM affect current? Since current is dependent on voltage (higher voltage allows for more current) decreasing analogue voltage reduces current, but what about PWM? If the actual voltage is only full/none, is the current also full/none or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current at any instant will be either full or none, but the average current over one cycle of PWM will depend on the pulse width.

If the pulse is high for 25% of the PWM cycle, the average current during that cycle will be 25% of the maximum ("full") current.